# Is there an issue with the review queue indicator today?

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues

I've noticed a few times when looking over at Stack Overflow today that I've had a big red dot on the review queue and thought "Ok, I'll go pitch in.", only to find that the review queue is empty.

[image]

I'm not sure whether this is some sort of issue on my side. Has anyone else seen this today?

Comment: It is unreliable by design.  The inevitable side-effect of latency and caching artifacts that web servers suffer from.

Comment: The red shows that there is a large number of items in the queue - however, you have gone through all of those items, so nothing for, you, specifically, to do. But the icon, as highlighted, is site-wide and not user specific.

Comment: That's the thing, I hadn't actually reviewed anything at that point, I saw the red dot, clicked into the queue and it was empty

Comment: FP, LA and Triage were at 0 pretty much all the time, I had struggles getting to 20 Reviews on each. I'd blame it on caching.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

As I type this, there are **31** active reviewers in the First Posts queue.

The queue is empty.

This suggests that the new indicator is perhaps a wee bit too effective at getting folks to drop what they're doing and jump in, all at once. A good problem to have, but frustrating for the good people like yourself who're trying to help out.

I've raised the "danger" threshold from 50 to 90 for both the First Posts and Late Answers queues. This should give us a little bit more breathing room when the indicator lights up.

Comment: While you are at, the close vote queue seems to be set to 10k. Could we lower it?

Comment: Also, why not take the 31 active reviewers into account and calculate the threshold dynamicly? To expensive db operation? Would this made a feature request?

Comment: We can lower it, @ChristianGollhardt; let's wait until activity has stabilized a bit first though. We just fixed a serious bug with this yesterday that'll likely alter the number of active reviewers considerably, at least in the short term. As for taking active reviewers into account... That's not particularly expensive, but it doesn't necessarily help - the indicator lights up in response to tasks that haven't been reviewed yet. If I see 30+ people active while there are no tasks, that suggests far more than 30 responded to the indicator - we need a threshold comfortably above that.

Comment: @Shog9 Is there a possibility that the grey circle only appear if there are 5+ (for example) reviews rather than 1? otherwise it's also possible to jump into a review queue and then find there's no reviews

Comment: That'd still be possible with 5+, @NickA, just as it's possible to see "5" next to a queue on the /review page and click through to find them all claimed; a second threshold would reduce the chances of that somewhat, but not entirely - and at the cost of making this even more confusing in cases where there *aren't* other reviewers jumping on the queue. Another option here might be to simply provide more direct access to *other* queues when the one you've chosen comes up empty; the current "done" page is a bit sparse.

Comment: @Shog9 is there anywhere to get stats on the review queues? It looks like this has change has been a massive success given I'm seeing very low numbers across the board - even the Close Queue is down to 8.2k!

Comment: We should probably wait until folks have a chance to get used to the changes before getting too excited, @user3788685... That said, initial results are good: last week saw a record number of active reviewers, with 9897 members of Stack Overflow pitching in at least once over the course of the week, more than have ever participated in /review in a single week in the entire history of the site. In terms of reviews, the numbers are more subdued - good but not exceptional. As a ratio of reviews to tasks created, the volume was the highest since March (before we reduced the # of reviews for edits).

Comment: Yay, I did a good(?)

Comment: If it helps, today I also experienced this back on The Workplace, where the Suggested Edit queue went red but no reviews availabe, here is the [meta post](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4891/red-dot-on-suggested-edit-review-queue) I raised over there.

Comment: Today, this situation happened [again](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4891/red-dot-on-suggested-edit-review-queue) to me back on The Workplace... time to raise the threshold there?

Comment: No... This was triggered by the queue having a pile of tag wiki excerpt edits, @DarkCygnus (yours, in fact). That's gonna be tricky to fix - they're only accessible to 5K+ users, but the queue doesn't know this until you try to edit (not that it matters for you, since you can't review your own edits - but it stops a lot of normal reviewers from clearing them). I cleared the queue for now; we're gonna have to think about this. See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277031/can-we-have-tag-wiki-and-wiki-excerpt-edit-reviews-in-a-separate-queue-to-sugges