# "Red dots" on "review queues popup" when all <3K queues are empty (stuck at zero)

Tags: bug, review-queues, suggested-edits, popup

The red dot on the *Review queues* popup is showing for Suggested Edits and Triage when the queues are empty.

---

**UPDATE** <sup>(by [rene](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene))</sup>:

As a matter of fact ***all review queues* (except Close and Reopen) are stuck at zero**. Which is probably the root cause for the confusing red dot.

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Related: [Is there an issue with the review queue indicator today?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358151/2675154)

Comment: @ivarni It's been at _danger-urgent_ level for a while, although no suggested edits seem to exist in the queue...?

Comment: @yivi Hmm.. you're right. Well actually I just managed to skip 2 reviews so there was *something* there.

Comment: It's either a persistent case of the [usual](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/), the review queue is not working properly, or the danger threshold is really, really low today...

Comment: Getting the same issue in triage queue

Comment: I'm pretty sure the *create review task* batch job is stuck. On the positive side: this might be the day we can finally clear that close vote queue ....

Comment: Just replicated with triage http://prntscr.com/kab7m8

Comment: I refreshed and got one for suggested edit, but that was just a test review :P

Comment: when I click on "all queues", I see all of the queues avalable for <3K are empty, quite unusual, no suggested edits, nor LQ, nothing...

Comment: @jps that's because it's the summer holidays, all the schools have finished so we have no homework questions till September. *OR it's bugged*

Comment: @Cerbrus it is at best related but the fact that all queues are empty is the real issue here. Unless you don't want that bug fixed.

Comment: So everything's an audit today?

Comment: I have just had 2 edit suggestions approved, maybe we are actually on top of the reviews today

Comment: Seems to have been fixed, it's been a solid half hour since the Red Dot disappeared

Comment: @rene "clear that close vote queue"-  better luck next time, it has grown from 7.7k to 8.1k since you posted ;)

Comment: @Yuca It is defenitely not fixed https://gyazo.com/ebf697ef159a6560922a52fadfef1841

Comment: @Granny I clicked on the red dot I believe three times throughout the morning. After the third time it stopped showing up.

Comment: How can I help filling the queue? Are flag enought ?

Comment: @Yuca you can clear the dot from the main review icon link but you cant clear the red dots from when the menu is dropped down

Comment: @WhatsThePoint oh wow, it wasn't like that in the morning, only 'Triage' had a red dot!

Comment: it looks like something has run now as I have a count on triage

Comment: @DragandDrop you can't. First Posts and Late Answers are filled by the system without user interaction, LQ and Triage are to a large part filled automatically, edit suggestions are submitted at a fairly stable rate. Flow of review worthy posts is stable meaning that if the queue is so reliably stuck at zero items then something in the system doesn't let review worthy posts get into the queues (see comment above about batch job being stuck)

Comment: I don't believe that the supposed duplicate applies. The answer from Shog would suggest that the review queues actually had 0 items in them, which I don't believe is the case here. I mean, what are the odds that *all* the <3k review queues have actually been empty for any length of time?

Comment: This seems to be resolved now, for me at least. The red dots are gone and there are items in the <3k queues.

Comment: This time really seems fixed :D

Comment: @Yuca Nope, [I'm still seeing this bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0G8iz.png) as of 22:15 BST.

Comment: Is fixed for me.

Comment: Yeah the problem seems to be fixed now. (2018-07-25 13:57 UTC)

Comment: I'm having a similar issue as well, currently on Puzzling.se. I've also seen it on Poker.se. I'll get the red dot overlay, but nothing to review. Currently on Puzzling, all the queues are empty, whereas in the past on Poker.se, I'll see on the review page that LQ is not empty, but I do not have access to it yet.