# Review queue "feature"/bug

Tags: discussion, review-queues, rate-limiting

Yesterday I got surprised by an old design of the review queue pop up menu. The gray dot, that indicates that there are posts that can be reviewed, has been replaced by a red dot. I just read [red-dots-on-review-queues-popup](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371482/red-dots-on-review-queues-popup-when-all-3k-queues-are-empty-stuck-at-zero): what explained why there is a red dot, but it did not match to my experience.

Once the red dot appeared there were lots of reviewable posts and I was able to review 40 posts per day in the Triage and First Posts queue. Moreover I saw that a few other users reviewed 40 posts as well.

So was this a test phase for some restructuring of the reviews per day limit or just a bug? Since today it isn't possible anymore.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) on Meta SE

> Reviewing
>
> - 20 reviews per queue per day if the queue size is less than 1000
> - 40 reviews per queue per day if the queue size is 1000 or more, or 150 for Triage
> - No review limit for ♦ mods

And from [When I look at the review icon, I see red](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355233/when-i-look-at-the-review-icon-i-see-red):

> Current "danger zone" thresholds (subject to change without notice) are:
>
> - Low Quality, First Posts & Late Answers: 90 tasks
> - Suggested Edits: 90 tasks
> - Triage: 100 tasks
> - Reopen and Help/Improvement: 150 tasks
> - Close: 10000 tasks

From this it is clear that when you were reviewing Triage the queue size was over 150 (as you could review more than 20), which is above the threshold of 100 which will have resulted in the queue having a red dot. You can also see that when you were reviewing First Posts it was over 1000 (again, as you could review more than 20), which is above the threshold of 90, this also have resulted in the queue having a red dot.

From looking at these thresholds you can see that there are periods when there will be a red dot but there won't be enough events in the queue for you to be able to review more than 20. It just happened that on the day you experienced this, there was.

---

So to answer your question:

> So was this a test phase for some restructuring of the reviews per day limit or just a bug?

Neither - It's a feature