# Red dot in the review icon even though I cannot review

Tags: bug, review-queues, top-bar

I like reviewing a lot, but sometimes I make mistakes. I am banned from reviewing until some time (end of April now). So no queues are showing for me. **I literally cannot review at the moment**, so it is not a [there is nothing to review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358151/is-there-an-issue-with-the-review-queue-indicator-today) thing.

But I noticed that from time to time I can see this red dot appearing. I've never seen it when I can review, but it usually appears when I have been banned for a little time on reviewing.

I have read several posts like [this one about not red dot in the queues themselves](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356697/top-bar-review-needed-red-dot-showing-but-no-red-dot-in-review-queues), [this one explaining the red dot basics](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353903/top-bar-review-drop-down-can-be-much-quicker) and [this one arguing that some people get to see it in the queues and some don't](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355233/when-i-look-at-the-review-icon-i-see-red).

My conclusion is that it is still in development, and there can be some errors (as you will see in these pictures below).

**Before clicking it:**

### [image: Before clicking it]

**After clicking it:**

[image: After clicking it]

By what I have been reading in here, delay and other stuff might be the problem. It really does not bother me but I was just asking myself why even not being able to review, still could see the dot.

Comment: WOW! Even though I seached especifically for that, I could not find it! Thanks! Should I delete the question? Or leave it because that one does not have an answer? (In case someone answers this one as it is more recent) @ErikA

Comment: That's up to you. You can also leave it here to indicate that the issue is still present and still is confusing people, and to serve as a signpost helping others find the question, if you wish. Note that it might catch downvotes if you do, but those don't affect reputation or bans on meta.

Comment: Downvotes are not something I'm actually bothered of! I'll leave it here to leave a "statement"(?) that the issue still exists! Thanks @ErikA

Comment: Same question! But still no answer to it! Thanks for the extra info though! @Luuklag

Comment: I can recall reading somewhere that his is by design. I can't find the proper reference though. Reasoning was that dev time shouldn't be spend on those not worthy of it / that this is such an edgecase that the benefit of improving here is too small.

Comment: Don't delete this bug report, for several reasons. 1. It may help future users find the original if they use the same search terms that you did, 2. More bug reports on the same topic is an indication that there's more interest in fixing that bug.

Comment: I agree! And as I said, it is not something that actually bothers me. I just wanted to point it out and know if it was a solution. The question is marked as a duplicate but  `and already has an answer here`is not quite right, but I guess it is how it's done when marking as a duplicate! @Luuklag

Comment: Yes, I will keep it here so users following a similar search to mine, can find other original questions by the duplicate (although there is no answer in those duplicates). Thanks  @MadaraUchiha -chan!