# Suggested Edits queue "This item is not reviewable"

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I was doing the Suggested Edits queue this morning and came across an [edit that is clearly spam](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23378463) and was probably meant to be an audit, yet it says

> This item is not reviewable.

It shows as being suggested by the Community user. What does this mean?

[image: image of the suggested edit]

Comment: @NickA What is the point of marking as a dupe of a 2-year-old question with no answers? Neither question will get answers and I'll still be left with the question.

Comment: Because it's a duplicate, it doesn't matter how old the question is or whether or not it has answers, a duplicate's a duplicate

Comment: Would you say the same about [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382388/red-dot-in-the-review-icon-even-though-i-cannot-review) pointing at a post a year and a half old? Having a post marked as a duplicate isn't inherently bad, it just means that there are more reports and that they're linked to each other.

Comment: @NickA For bug reports, sure, but is this a bug? I haven't tagged it [meta-tag:bug] because I'm not sure if it actually is a bug.

Comment: @NickA I'm also not convinced that marking a dupe as a dupe is always right. Say you've got some programming question. It's niche, but has been asked 2 years prior... but alas, is unanswered. You have no path left to you but to create a new question, and it naturally gets marked as a dupe. The question gets marked with `[duplicate]` so answerers are now unlikely to view the closed question, even less likely to continue through to the older duplicate-source and _even if they answer_ that older question the new OP will never know. It's lose-lose for question-asker #2.

Comment: On SO you cannot choose a question with no answer as a duplicate target. I'm surprised it is possible on meta.